# startservice not working for service with process attribute

Tags: android, multithreading, service

I have a very simple service, trying to run it in a separate process, but the `startService()` method has no effect at all unless I made it run in the same process [removed the process attribute from manifest]!

Service:

```
public class RemoteService extends Service {

    /** Called when the service is being created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        Log.v("RemoteService", "Service:onCreate===> called");
    }

    /** The service is starting, due to a call to startService() */
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.v("RemoteService", "Service:onStartCommand===> called");
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    /** A client is binding to the service with bindService() */
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        Log.v("RemoteService", "Service:onBind===> called");
        return null;
    }
    /** Called when a client is binding to the service with bindService()*/
    @Override
    public void onRebind(Intent intent) {
        Log.v("RemoteService", "Service:onRebind===> called");
    }

    /** Called when The service is no longer used and is being destroyed */
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Log.v("RemoteService", "Service:onDestroy===> called");

    }
}
```

Manifest:

```
<service
    android:name=".RemoteService"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="false"
    android:process=":worker"></service>
```

Activity:

```
startService(new Intent(this, RemoteService.class));
```

**So, how to start service that has the `process` attribute?**

Comment: how do you know it's not working

Comment: @TimCastelijns the logs never shows up, especially the onCreate log

Comment: are you filtering logs for the correct process?

Comment: @TimCastelijns Thanks! I was not seeing logs, filter has hided them!. It is working fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to filter the logs in the logcat for the correct process. Since the service runs in a different process you do not always see them by default.